# SQLite - multiple random result sets with unions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, union

I want to do two SQL queries and get random results returned from each query and then union them together, a bit like this:

```
select colA, colB, colC
from tableA
order by random() limit 10

union all

select colA, colB, colC
from tableB
order by random() limit 10
```

It doesn't let me do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think I've solved this now. I don't actually know how this site works but I've done it by doing something like this:

```
select * from ( 
   select colA, colB, colC 
   from tableA 
   order by random() limit 10 
) 
union all 

select * from ( 
   select colA, colB, colC 
   from tableB 
   order by random() limit 10 
)
```